# How to view specific changes in data at particular version in Delta Lake

Tags: scala, apache-spark, delta-lake, data-quality

Right now I have one test data which have 1 partition and inside that partition it has 2 parquet files

If I read data as:

```
val df = spark.read.format("delta").load("./test1510/table@v1")
```

Then I get latest data with 10,000 rows and if I read:

```
val df = spark.read.format("delta").load("./test1510/table@v0")
```

Then I get 612 rows, now my question is: How can I view only those new rows which were added in version 1 which is 10,000 - 612 = 9388 rows only

In short at each version I just want to view which data changed. Overall in delta log I am able to see json files and inside there json file I can see that it create separate parquet file at each version but how can I view it in code ?

I am using Spark with Scala

Comment: How about joining the two where a key not exists in the second set (v0)?

Answer (score 3):

you don't even need to go at `parquet` file level. you could simply use SQL query to achieve this.

```
%sql 
SELECT * FROM test_delta VERSION AS OF 2 minus SELECT * FROM test_delta VERSION AS OF 1
```

Above code will give you a newly added rows in version 2 which were not in version 1

in your case you can do the following

```
val df1 = spark.read.format("delta").load("./test1510/table@v1")
val df2 = spark.read.format("delta").load("./test1510/table@v0")
display(df2.except(df1))
```